# Missing rows in full outer join

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, outer-join

I am trying to count how many users are observed on each of the 3 consecutive days.
Each of the 3 intermediate tables (`t0`, `t1`, `t2`) has 2 columns: `uid` (unique ID) and `d0` (or
`d1` or `d2`, which is 1 and indicates that the user is observed on that day).

The following query:

```sql
select d0,d1,d2, count(*) as user_count from (
select uid, 1 as d0
from my_table
where day=5 and uid is not Null
group by uid
) as t0 full outer join (
select uid, 1 as d1
from my_table
where day=6 and uid is not Null
group by uid
) as t1 on t0.uid = t1.uid
full outer join (
select uid, 1 as d2
from my_table
where day=7 and uid is not Null
group by uid
) as t2 on t0.uid = t2.uid and t1.uid = t2.uid
group by d0,d1,d2 order by d0,d1,d2
```

produces this output from `spark.sql(q).toPandas().set_index(["d0","d1","d2"])`:

```
          user_count
d0 d1 d2            
0  0  1        73455
   1  0        53345
1  0  0        49254
   1  0         8234
      1        78455
```

Two rows are obviously missing: `0 1 1` and `1 0 1`. ***Why***?!

PS1. I understand why `0 0 0` is missing.

PS2. `my_table` looks approximately like this:

```sql
create table my_table (uid integer, day integer);
insert into my_table values
 (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7),
 (2, 5), (2, 6),
 (3, 5), (3, 7),
 (4, 6), (4, 7),
 (5, 5),
 (6, 6),
 (7, 7);
```

For this table I expect the query to return

```
          user_count
d0 d1 d2            
0  0  1        1      --- uid = 7
   1  0        1      --- uid = 6
      1        1      --- uid = 4
1  0  0        1      --- uid = 5
      1        1      --- uid = 3
   1  0        1      --- uid = 2
      1        1      --- uid = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the original query the last `FULL JOIN` should take into account `t0.uid` could be null due to the first `FULL JOIN` so it must be OR not AND.

```
select d0,d1,d2, count(*) as user_count 
from (
   select uid, 1 as d0
   from my_table
   where day=5 and uid is not Null
   group by uid
) as t0 
full outer join (
   select uid, 1 as d1
   from my_table
   where day=6 and uid is not Null
   group by uid
) as t1 on t0.uid = t1.uid
full outer join (
   select uid, 1 as d2
   from my_table
   where day=7 and uid is not Null
   group by uid
) as t2 on t0.uid = t2.uid or t1.uid = t2.uid
group by d0,d1,d2 
order by d0,d1,d2;
```

[SQL Server db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7f0947da18a53ed907849d5300f84fb)

Personally I would stick with the Gordon Linoff's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use two levels of aggregation instead of `full join`:

```
select d0, d1, d2, count(*)
from (select uid,
             max(case when day = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as d0,
             max(case when day = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as d1,
             max(case when day = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as d2
      from my_table
      where uid is not Null
      group by uid
     ) u
group by d0, d1, d2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, but I am also eager to learn what I am doing wrong with my query.

Comment: @sds . . . If you just want a flag rather than a count, then use `max()` rather than a more complicated expression.  This is much the better way of solving the problem -- two aggregations as opposed to four aggregations and two joins.